# Which is correct: I could come your home today? or I could come TO your home today?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I'm confused about whether to say "come your home" or "come to your home." I saw a video by EnglishWale on YouTube on how to use *could* in a sentence. For past possibilities, he used this sentence:

> I could come home today.

I think come *to* should be used, but I could be wrong. Please clear my doubt.

Comment: *I'm confused about whether to say "come to your home" or "come to your home."*  Those sentences are the same.  Could you check your post again, please?

Comment: @stangdon I assume the title is correct and that was a typo, especially considering the rest of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your confusion comes from the fact that "home" can be used as either a noun or an adverb.

"Home" used as an adverb ([merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/home) entry 2 sense 1) doesn't need any qualifiers or prepositions. It means means "to my/our/your home." You would use it as follows:

> "I'm going home tomorrow" (*home* = to my home)
>
> "Are you coming home tomorrow?" (*home* = to our home)
>
> "Go home." (*home* = to your home)

"Home" used as a noun ([merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/home) entry 1 sense 1) requires a preposition and additional adjectives/articles.

> "Can I come to your home tomorrow?"
>
> "I'm going to Sarah's home on Tuesday."

Regardless, if you're asking a question, you would need to switch the first two words of your sentence: "Could I" not "I could".